# How to echo in PHP the AS keyword of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
select date_format(`user_info`.`created`,"%b %d, %Y") as `Date`,count(`user_info`.`email`) as `Registered Members` from `user_info` 
                where  [dynamic_filters] group by year(`user_info`.`created`),month(`user_info`.`created`),day(`user_info`.`created`) 
                order by year(`user_info`.`created`),month(`user_info`.`created`),day(`user_info`.`created`)
```

I don't know how to echo the AS keyword in PHP

Comment: Do you use `PDO`, `mysqli_*` functions or something else to interact with your DB?

Comment: I used mysqli_*

Comment: What do you mean by 'echoing the AS keyword'? If it's about field aliases, you can just use the alias in in the result array, e.g `$row['Date']`.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol, I run my codes. Thanks a lot.